# Swift - How to actually switch targets once custom flags in compiler are made?

Tags: ios, swift, target, flags

Ok, so I totally understand how to make two different targets within the same Swift project. I also get how to switch between the targets manually, i.e. setting the active scheme manually in xcode. However, I do not understand how to actually switch between targets once the app is running.

For example, if I have both a paid and free version of the same app in the same swift project, how do I access the paid version? It seems that I can only run one active scheme at a time, and I don't know how to switch targets while the app is running. Maybe that isn't possible or is poor programming technique, but there must be a way to do something like "once user pays 99 cents don't show user ads anymore."

I've submitted apps to the store in the past, but they only ever contain one target.

Ultimately, my question is this: "How do you switch between targets WHILE an app is active?"

Comment: The target dictates how the app is compiled, not only how it runs.  My guess is that your compiler flags and targets are completely eliminating some code/assets from the free version of your app, so there is no way to switch.  To change this, you could add a variable that stores whether or not the user has unlocked the paid content, and have it set to true for the paid version, and false for the free one.

Comment: Well put. The better approach seems not to make two targets, rather just one target with variables that enable / disable paid content... Another question though - using your approach, would I have to make two targets, and therefore two apps?

Comment: One approach would be to have a `contentUnlockedByDefault` constant which would be manually set before building for the App Store. Another way (which I think is less error prone), is to create two targets which set the `contentUnlockedByDefault` constant appropriately using a compiler flag or something. That way its easier to tell which version is being built. Also with the two targets, its possible to exclude all of the IAP code from the paid version.

Comment: Ok I see, however, when creating two targets will the user have to re-download the app from the store? I'm confused as to how that process works. And when you say "exclude all IAP code from the paid version", this is because only the free version needs the IAP code in order to enable the paid version?

Comment: Thats correct. The user won't need to re-download the app since the free version would have the paid content already, its just locked.

Comment: Oh ok, how come then when I run the free and paid versions in the Xcode simulator it loads both apps separately?

Comment: Also, how to I programmatically change the targets? I know you mentioned this before, but I still don't understand.

Comment: Do you know what I'm asking? I totally see the wisdom of what you're saying - using two targets. I just don't see how ( and where ) to call that programatically. Do I do so from the AppDelegate? Would you give me a code example?

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do what skrundz says or you can simply use NSUserDefaults and some simple variables. Personally I don't like approach of making two targets bc its a lot of code to keep track of. there are good tutorials on here about how to make free and paid versions of same app without using two targets.

Answer (score 1):

no no, the best way ( and programming etiquette ) is to make two separate targets.